# Generics in Kotlin: how to access companion object

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have 2 enums

```
enum class Enum1{
    X1, X2, X3, X4;
    companion object {
        val default = X2
    }
}
enum class Enum2{
    Y1, Y2, Y3;
    companion object {
        val default = Y3
    }
}
```

Both of them have companion object with a `default` variable.

Than I have two methods that returns this value

```
private fun printDefaultEnum1() : String{
    return Enum1.default.toString()
}

private fun printDefaultEnum2() : String{
    return Enum2.default.toString()
}
```

Is it possible in Kotlin to optimize this code and have only one generic method that accepts a type and prints corresponding value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this by using the fact that companion objects can implement interfaces:

```
interface DefaultEnum<E : Enum<E>> {
    val default: E
}

fun genericPrint(e: DefaultEnum<*>): String = e.default.toString()
```

This can then be used as following:

```
companion object : DefaultEnum<Enum1> {
    override val default: Enum1 = X2
}

genericPrint(Enum1) // This calls it with the companion object of Enum1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enum class Enum1 {
    X1, X2, X3, X4;
    companion object {
        val default = X2
    }

    override fun toString(): String = default.toString()
}

enum class Enum2 {
    Y1, Y2, Y3;
    companion object {
        val default = Y3
    }

    override fun toString(): String = default.toString()
}

private fun genericPrint(any: Any) {
    println(any.toString())
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    genericPrint(Enum1)
}
```

Or, even more simply:

```
enum class Enum1 {
    X1, X2, X3, X4;
    companion object {
        val default = X2
    }

    override fun toString(): String = default.toString()
}

enum class Enum2 {
    Y1, Y2, Y3;
    companion object {
        val default = Y3
    }

    override fun toString(): String = default.toString()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Enum1.toString())
}
```